# Burned a movie on DVD but only 10s of it is playable

Tags: windows-7, dvd-burning, nero

I used Nero 10 on Win7 x64 to burn an .avi movie onto DVD-RW (burned it as data project). When I insert it into the dvd player, it starts playing but after 10s, it stops. I tried burning it again, but the same happens. I burned it onto a regular DVD-R, but the same happens.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Could this be some error in the movie file? I can play it in win7 with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burning as Data will simply create a DVD with your AVI file on it.

It is then up to your DVD player to be able to play this file.

It is likely that the DVD player is at fault, not the burning.

To confirm this, put the DVD-R back into your computer and try opening the AVI in Windows directly from the DVD-R, not the original file and see what happens.

If it plays fine then the DVD Player is the problem and it cannot properly play the AVI.

You will need to convert it to a DVD format and burn this as a proper Video DVD.

I am not sure how this is done in Nero as I haven't used it for many years but I recall it has a function to do this.

I personally use [TMPGEnc Video Mastering Works](http://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/tvmw5.html) to convert to DVD but this is not a free product.

There are many [guides](http://www.videohelp.com/guides/category/newbie-all-in-one-dvd-convert-guides-4;62#4;62) available at [VideoHelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/guides?formatconversionselect=AVI%20to%20DVD) for AVI to DVD conversion using both free and paid-for tools.

Comment: It's just started to happen. A few days ago I burned the same .avi and watched it on the same dvd player (connected to my tv). Yesterday, I started getting this error. Could this be a sign that the PC DVD writer has fault and needs replacement?

Comment: as I said, can the pc read the avi off the dvd?

Comment: yes it can. it seems that there is a problem if I burn the .avi file which has white spaces in its name. funny...

Comment: must be something to do with the media chipset on the DVD player - remember, DVD players don't play AVI by default, they need an extra multimedia chip to do so and they are not all created equal!